# Public IP Address of the service/load balancer in Kubernetes from Env

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a nodejs app which has refers to the IP Address of the kubernetes service/load balancer public IP. Is there a way to get it from the process/env variables in runtime?

e..g `process.env.ENV_VARIABLE` and what is the env variable name

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's **not available** as an environment variable. Also keep in mind that a pod can receive traffic from multiple load balancers and also the external IP could change after the Pod started, leaving a stale value; so an IP in an environment variable might not be an adequate solution.

If you are using an **Ingress** object you can determine it's external IP by querying the Kubernetes apiserver (try `kubectl get myingress -o yaml`, see the `status:` part).

For a particular incoming **http request** check the `X-Forwarded-For:` header for the load balancer's IP.

Since the question is tagged [google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine), you can also use **gcloud** to get that IP (perhaps from an [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) or at startup):

- If you are using Ingress: `gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe k8s-fw-YOURNAMESPACE-YOURINGRESSNAME--YOURHASHVALUE --global --format='value(IPAddress)'`
- If you have a static IP reserved: `gcloud compute addresses describe my-static-ip-name --global --format='value(address)'`